Trying to create a TraceFlag with Apex, getting a Bad Request error
I'm trying to initiate a trace flag from invocable apex in an attempt to track down a transient error in an experience cloud screen flow.
I may parameterize this later, but currently I'm just trying to initiate the trace flag, and I'm stuck with this error: System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
Update: I removed the trailing space, used json.serialize, and got a little smarter with my debugging. Then was able to learn that DebugLevelId is required (and the individual debug level settings are not?). I have since added it but am getting the error "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 7dl160000008OKa" with that being the id of the DebugLevel.
Any ideas? Below is the updated code:
global without sharing class StartTraceCurrentUser {
@InvocableMethod(label='Start User Trace' description='Starts one-hour current user debug trace')
public static void StartLog(){
    
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');   
    req.setEndpoint(url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v61.0/tooling/sobjects/TraceFlag/');
    
    Map<String, String> traceflag = new Map<String, String>();
    traceflag.put('TracedEntityId',UserInfo.getUserId());
    traceflag.put('StartDate',datetime.now().formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\''));
    traceflag.put('ExpirationDate',datetime.now().addminutes(60).formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\''));
    traceflag.put('DebugLevelId','7dl160000008OKaAAM');
    traceflag.put('LogType','USER_DEBUG');
    /*traceflag.put('ApexCode','DEBUG');
    traceflag.put('ApexProfiling','INFO');
    traceflag.put('Callout','INFO');
    traceflag.put('Database','INFO');
    traceflag.put('System','INFO');
    traceflag.put('Validation','INFO');
    traceflag.put('Visualforce','INFO');
    traceflag.put('Workflow','DEBUG');*/
    
    string reqBody = json.serialize(traceflag);
    
    
    system.debug(reqBody);
    
    req.setBody(reqBody);
    req.setMethod('POST'); 
    try{
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        system.debug(res.getBody());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        system.debug( 'Post Error:' +e.getMessage());
        }

   
    
}

Here is the TraceFlag documentation.
Thanks for your help!

I very highly recommend you switch to JSON.serialize over string concatenation to build your request body. If what you've put in your post here is actually what the request body reads, then terminating with ,& is absolutely the problem.

That's just where the debug statement cuts off, I believe. But I'm more than willing to try your approach.

Trailing space in USER_DEBUG  ?

Sharp eye @cropredy!

Scott -- did that resolve your issue? if so, I'll write up an answer

I haven't had a chance to try it yet. Holidays and such.

New error, new code above.
